# Expired Patents due to fees?

Tags: fees

Application US09/062,017 events
1998-04-17
Application filed by Thellmann; Rick
1998-04-17
Priority to US09/062,017
2000-01-11
Application granted
2000-01-11
Publication of US6013181A
2018-04-17
Anticipated expiration
Status
Expired - Fee Related  (Can I make a Payment to bring my patent current?)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a lawyer, but according to the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) the priority date for US6013181A is 04-17-1998. Even if you had kept the fees up to date, the patent whould have expired on 04-17-2018 so I would guess that there is nothing you can do to revive it. I can see no patent term extensions.